# Hide area of an SCNMaterial

Tags: shader, scenekit, mask, arkit, scnmaterial

I'm using SceneKit and ARKit 1.5, once a surface has been mapped I apply a material to it.

I would like to only show what's under the camera in a certain radius with an alpha effect. I want to keep the material static meaning that it does not move when the camera moves, only the radius shape will move.

What kind of technique could I use for this ?

ArCore by Google does this perfectly.

Actual rendering: 
[image]

Desired Rendering:
[image]

ARCore example: (click to see GIF)

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: idea is to move a plane on top of detected plane.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a shader modifier to achieve that.

Using the [`.surface`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypoint/1523791-surface) entry point you could set `_surface.transparent` to a value that depends on the distance between the shaded point and the point of view:

```
_surface.transparent = attenuation(length(_surface.position));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to use _surface.transparent but it modifies the entire surface transparency. 
I'd like to make just a part of the surface transparent in a circle shape like in my pictures. 
How could I define a transparent / non transparent area using shaders ?

Comment: A surface modifier is applied per-pixel. If the entire surface becomes transparent then your attenuation function needs more tuning.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge to write the attenuation function shader code at this point (though I would love too). So far using Apple doc I was able to make transparent stripes on a material but that's all.